# P2P networks with search, and intranet traveling

Tags: vpn

Which P2P networks have an integrated search that can reach widest range of content/nodes ?

Is there P2P networks and software, that would support finding and connecting to nodes by using data on other nodes within the network, and running searches in relevant places regardless of their location and the node-path ?

Answer (score 1):

eDonkey servers support search, but i'm not sure about how it relates to the server-server connections,

bitTorrent has a DHT search (not sure if it can be unlimited in deepness/scale), https://forum.bittorrent.com/topic/52041-search/,

Gnutella currently seem to have 4 servers/"ultra"[_] search deepness limit,

thats mostly a guess, but Perfect Dark possibly using a "tree search" that passes trough the whole network under control of an upper nodes .

and i haven't found much info about the intra-network observe-traveling .